# Translations are not saved correctly using A2lix Translation + KnpLabs DoctrineBehaviors

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, a2lix-translation

In my Symfony project I use **SonataAdminBundle** and **A2lixTranslationForm + KnpLabsDoctrineBehaviors** bundles for multi-language support.

I have **Serial** and **Episode** entities which use standard **OneToMany** and **ManyToOne** relationship. I display episodes using **sonata_type_collection**:

```
->add('episodes', 'sonata_type_collection', [
        'by_reference' => false,
    ], 
    [
        'edit' => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table',
    ]
)
```

By default A2lixTranslation bundle displays translatable fields under each other. However, I need to display each translation field of the episode in its own column. In order to achieve this, I created three virtual fields with the same **property_path**:

```
           ->add('episode_title', 'a2lix_translations', [
                'property_path' => 'translations',
                'fields' => [
                    'title' => [
                        'attr' => [
                            'pattern' => false,
                        ],
                        'label' => false,
                    ],
                ],
                'exclude_fields' => ['subTitle', 'description'],
                'label' => 'Title',
            ])
            ->add('episode_subtitle', 'a2lix_translations', [
                'property_path' => 'translations',
                'fields' => [
                    'subTitle' => [
                        'label' => false,
                    ],
                ],
                'exclude_fields' => ['title', 'description'],
                'label' => 'Subtitle',
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('episode_description', 'a2lix_translations', [
                'property_path' => 'translations',
                'fields' => [
                    'description' => [
                        'field_type' => 'textarea',
                        'label' => false,
                    ],
                ],
                'exclude_fields' => ['title', 'subTitle'],
                'label' => 'Description',
                'required' => false,
            ])
```

As you can see, I display only one field in each **a2lix_translations** form.

But I faced the following problem: only the last field value (**description** in this case) is saved when I add new episode using **Add new** button of the collection form and then clicking **Update** button of the parent (**Serial**)  form. Wherein already existing episodes are saved correctly if edited.

Could you please point me why is this happening and how to fix the issue. I suppose each translations form values rewrite the previous ones, but why do this work normally when saving existing records? 
Or maybe there is another way to display each field in the own column in sonata collection form, this also will be helpful.

Thank you.